# Stepper motor and L293dne getting hot

Tags: stepper-motor

I purchased [some steppers motors](http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&_trksid=p4340.l2557&rt=nc&nma=true&item=120702651462&si=3gsUkig29Quejyid2uHntNf4gxc%253D&viewitem=&sspagename=STRK%3aMEWNX%3aIT#ht_636wt_1139) with relatively little known about the specs.  I'm hoping to drive them with a [L293DNE wired up like this](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StepperBipolarCircuit).  I've got it working and it all seems to be going well - except the L293DNE is getting quite hot.  It would burn my finger quite quickly if I left it running long.

I understand they can run quite hot, but I'd rather not have it that hot if I can reduce it.  I require minimal torque for my application, so I was hoping to be able to run it off a 5v 700ma wall wart.

I'm pretty new to all this, but I thought increasing the resistance would lower the current and solve my problem, but it didn't didn't seem to help (or very possibly I did it wrong).

What should I do to reduce the heat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use L298s with heat sinks. They can handle a lot more current and are intended for use with heat sinks, unlike the DIL L293D.

Comment: I think the advice to use something other than a L293 is more sound than I thought a month ago.

Answer (score 0):

Open loop drivers of this sort work best when the back EMF of the load does the work of limiting current; i.e. there is very little load.  In the case of a stepper motor, this generally means that the motor is moving a light load quickly, with only rare 'hold' operations.

Higher loads normally require current sensing, or at least some form of current limiting.  Some drivers, for example the [L298](http://www.st.com/stonline/books/pdf/docs/1773.pdf), can do this by measuring the voltage across a resistor in series with the outputs.

Alternatively, if you have a good idea about what your load will look like, you can use the same L293 with a reduced duty cycle during periods of high load, just estimating how much current the motor will draw.